# Как найти элемент и кликнуть по нему?

Tags: python, selenium

Есть такая кнопка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, как она описана в HTML:

```
<button data-v-4318eb75="" data-v-f5ddf1e8="" class="button-secondary button-secondary--dark">
                Dota 2
            <!----></button>
```

Я пытаюсь найти эту кнопку через SELENIUM и кликнуть по ней, но не получается. Может, я не так ищу?
Отправьте, пожалуйста, доступный пример как найти элемент и кликнуть по нему. В силу слабого знания английского я не могу разобраться в их документации.
Мой код:

```
driver.get('https://csgoempire.gg/withdraw')

xpath = '/button[class="button-secondary button-secondary--gold"]'
search = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]
search.click()
```

Comment: В коде dark, у тебя gold.

Comment: Переделал, но не работает. Не находит таких элементов. В независимости от того, сколько слешей стоит вначале
xpath = '///button[class="button-secondary button-secondary--dark"]'

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста )

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в пробеле. Попробуйте xpath = '/button[class="button-secondary\u00a0button-secondary--dark"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде несколько ошибок:

- Неправильно указан класс кнопки `(class="button-secondary button-secondary--gold"` вместо `button-secondary button-secondary--dark`)
- При использовании `/` Selenium будет искать элемент в корне текущего элемента, что почти всегда не верно
- Используется XPath для поиска элемента, который можно найти по CSS локатору

Данный код должен решить проблемму:

```
search = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.button-secondary.button-secondary--dark')
```